# How to hide cell asp code

Tags: c#, asp.net

it is impossible to hide the cell thus

```
<% if(link){ %>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell >Action</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <% } %>
```

Writes: `The blocks of code in this context is not supported.`

Creating a new table is too problematic.

Any tips, link or code example would be useful.

Comment: All server side elements should have `runat="server"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically all visible/not visible type manipulation should be done with Javascript client side. Using `jQuery` and pointing to the ID of an element to hide it is trivial. However, since you have decided to use an `ASP.NET` server side control in the way of a `TableHeaderCell`, you *can* change its `.Visible` property [server side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableheadercell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the `C#` code if you wish:

```
if (isSomeCondition)
{
  this.TableHeaderCell1.Visible = false;
}
```

You will have to assign an `ID` to that control in the markup as well to have it's handle:

```
<asp:TableHeaderCell id="TableHeaderCell1">
```

I still *heavily* opt for a client side approach to hiding elements, and you can still do this with the following syntax:

```
$('#<%= TableHeaderCell1.ClientID %>').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gridview control you can do something like this:

```
 if (link)
            {
                gridview.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            }
```